# How to write a regular expression that can matches the whole function @Prompt (…) whatever written inside () even if it contains another ()

Tags: java, sql, regex

For example I want replace  any prompt function in an SQL query 
I have used this expression

`Query = Query.replaceAll("@prompt\\s*\\(.*?\\)", "(1)");`

This expression works in this example

```
@Prompt('Bill Cycle','A','MIGRATION\BC',,,)
```

@Prompt('Bill Cycle','A','MIGRATION\BC',,,)

and the output is is `(1)`

but when it does not work on this example

```
@Prompt('Groups','A','[Lookup] Price Group (2)\Nested Group',,,)
```

the out put is `(1) \Nested Group',,,)` which is not valid

Comment: If you expect it to reject unmatched brackets, then this cannot be done with a regular expression.

Comment: @JoeC So Is there any way to neglect the parenthesis inside single Quotes

Comment: what should the output in this case `@Prompt('Bill Cycle','A','MIGRATION\BC',,,)@Prompt('Bill Cycle','A','MIGRATION\BC',,,)` ?

Comment: @YCF_L the output should be just the replacement which I wrote here (1)

Comment: so it should if there are two @Prompt you will get only `(1)` right?

Comment: @YCF No,  (1) for each one. For example

@Prompt('x',,,,,) = @Prompt('y',,,)

The output is (1) = (1)

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) - this is a problem for a proper parser, not regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, as pointed out by Joe C in a comment, what you are trying to do cannot be done in a regular expression for arbitrary depth parenthesis. The reason is because regular-expressions are not capable of "counting". You need a stack machine for that, or a context-free language parser.

However, you also suggest that the 'prompted' content is always inside single quotes. I assume below the standard Java regexp library. Other regexp libraries might need translation...

```
"@Prompt\\('[^']*'(\s*,\s*(('[^']*')|([^',)]*)))*\\)"
```

So, you are searching within prompt for blocks of single-quoted text. The search assumes that each internal bit of content is enclosed in single quotes.

Verify at https://regex101.com/r/nByy0Y/1 (I made a couple fixes). Note that at regex101.com, it will treat the double back-slash as intending a literal back-slash. What you want instead is just to quote the parenthesis so that you want a literal parenthesis.

Comment: Could you please recheck it ? it gives an illegal character error

Comment: Are you using Java regexp? Or which regexp library?

Comment: I am using replaceAll function in Java

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/F6CIWg/1 Gives a link to the tests I ran using regex101.com. In java, you will need to change the single back-slash to a double-backslash.

Comment: Is the use of quotes for an element optional (except in the case of parenthesis)? If so, the regexp will need to be modified to account for that.

Comment: I put an example of query here and it does not match to your regular expression 

https://regex101.com/r/nByy0Y/1

Comment: Got it. In a meeting at the moment - I can fix this, but it will take about an hour before I am able to look at it again. The basic idea is to make the quoting optional.

Comment: Take your time Mr Bill

Comment: FYI: Update is complete. I'm not sure if you can see my edits at https://regex101.com/r/nByy0Y/1, but I tested the changes there with your SQL statement.

Comment: No, the updates is not shown can you put it another link please

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using the lazy quantifier '?', it is stopping the match at the end of the first ')'. removing that will let it go to the end greedily, as such:

```
@prompt\(.*\)
```

But if there is concern that the entries may have more parans after the one in question, it will cause problems.

Assuming the additional parens will always be in quotes, you can do this:

```
@prompt\((('([^'])*',*)*|(.*,*)*)\)
```

Here is it looking for items wrapped in single quotes OR text without parens, which should capture all of the single quoted elements or null params or unquoted text params

Comment: Unfortunately, Yes there is other parenthesis

Comment: yea, sounds like a tough case for regex, may need to parse the result sets that do have the case. can you show an example of when there are other parens following the one we care about.

Comment: @Amir Azzam see if my second regex above works with your dataset

Comment: No it is not working
Here is a two examples you can test on 

1. @prompt('price groups sub-groups','a','[lookup] price group (2)\nested price group',multi,constrained,not_persistent)


2.  @prompt('desired %','n',,mono,free,not_persistent)

Comment: @Amir Azzam I updated the second regex and I believe it matches all of your cases now